# How to print available tags while using Robot Framework

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

If I have a large test suite in Robot Framework and a lot of tags is it possible to to get to know a list of tag names available within the suite  ?

some thing like pybot --listtags  ??

It will be useful for the person who is actually going to run the test.

For example in a scenario related to publishing of news articles , the test cases may be tagged as "publish", "published", or "publishing" .

The tester is not going to have RIDE at his/her disposal . And hence he/she may not know the exact tag name .

Under these circumstances I thought it will be useful to extract the available tags to display - without running any tests . And then he/she can choose to run the test with the desired tag

I searched the robot framework user guide and didn't see any command line options that do this.

Comment: @downvoter may I know why you felt it was a bad question

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you really just need a list of all the tags used throughout the suite?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question shows no effort at doing research, and many people find that to be a valid reason to downvote. Note that the tooltip for the downvote button begins with "This question does not show any research effort..."

Comment: @BryanOakley I admit the question was very short, but that doesnt mean that I didnt look for the answer of my own, I went through the RF userguide for this and didnt find an inbuilt way. I thought this is a natural feature anybody would like, because RF by its nature provides a lot of features that it's users never thought about. Anyways your script is nice, thanks alot for the time :)

Comment: Understood. If you had shared that information in your question, perhaps it wouldn't have been downloaded. For example, you could have written something like "I searched the robot framework user guide and didn't see any command line options that do this, and I searched the tools section of the robotframework.org site and also didn't find anything".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing provided by robot to give you this information. However, it's pretty easy to write a python script that uses the robot parser to get all of the tag information. Here's a quick hack that I think is correct (though I only tested it very briefly):

```
from robot.parsing import TestData
import sys

def main(path):
    suite = TestData(parent=None, source=path)
    tags = get_tags(suite)
    print ", ".join(sorted(set(tags)))

def get_tags(suite):
    tags = []

    if suite.setting_table.force_tags:
        tags.extend(suite.setting_table.force_tags.value)

    if suite.setting_table.default_tags:
        tags.extend(suite.setting_table.default_tags.value)

    for testcase in suite.testcase_table.tests:
        if testcase.tags:
            tags.extend(testcase.tags.value)

    for child_suite in suite.children:
        tags.extend(get_tags(child_suite))

    return tags

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Note that this will *not* get any tags created by the [Set Tags](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Set%20Tags) keyword, nor does it take into account tags removed by [Remove Tags](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Remove%20Tags).

Save the code to a file, eg get_tags.py, and run it like this:

```
$ python /tmp/get_tags.py /tmp/tests/
a tag, another force tag, another tag, default tag, force tag, tag-1, tag-2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a Robot Framework output file [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) to list all tags of the current suite.

```
from lxml import etree as XML

"""Listener that prints the tags of the executed suite."""

ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

tags_xpath = ".//tags/tag"

def output_file(path):
    root = XML.parse(path).getroot()
    tag_elements = root.xpath(tags_xpath)

    tags = set()

    for element in tag_elements:
        tags.add(element.text)

    print("\nExisting tags: " + str(tags) + "\n")
```

You can use such listener along with [dry run](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dry-run) mode to quickly get the tag data of a suite.

```
robot --listener get_tags.py --dryrun ./tests
```

The tags will be listed at the output file section of the console log.

```
==============================================================================

Existing tags: {'Tag1', 'a', 'Tag3.5', 'Feature1', 'b', 'Tag3', 'Feature2'}

Output:  D:\robot_framework\output.xml
Log:     D:\robot_framework\log.html
Report:  D:\robot_framework\report.html
```

Comment: Docs said, "The current tags are available as a built-in variable @{TEST TAGS}" at https://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Tags

Answer (score 1):

In robot 3.2, the API is [different](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.2.2/autodoc/robot.parsing.html) and the following is what I did:

```
from robot.api import get_model
import ast
def _check_tags(self, file):
    class TestTagPrint(ast.NodeVisitor):
        def visit_File(self, node):
            print(f"{node.source}")
            # to get suite level force tags
            for section in node.sections:
                for sect in section.body:
                    try:
                        if sect.type == 'FORCE_TAGS':
                            print(sect.values)
                    except AttributeError as ae:
                        pass
                    self.generic_visit(node)
    
        def visit_TestCase(self, node):
            for statement in node.body:
            # to get tags at test case level
               if statement.type == "TAGS":
                    print(statement.values)
    
model = get_model(file)
printer = TestTagPrint()
printer.visit(model)
```

Both print statements would return tuple.
There might be a simpler or better way in this API.
And I see API is different for Robot framework 4.