# How to get testcases [Tags] from robot framework

Tags: python, tags, robotframework, built-in, testcase

There is some 'test_suite.robot' file, that contains several test cases with specific tags.

```
*** Settings ***

*** Test Cases ***
TC One
    [Documentation]     ...
    [Tags]              one
    Log to console...

TC Two
    [Documentation]     ...
    [Tags]              two
    Log to console...
```

I need to get [Tags] values in my method in python file. How can I get them (in details)?

I know, that Robot provides several automatic variables. Among these are ${TEST NAME}, ${TEST DOCUMENTATION} and @{TEST TAGS}.

In python I get suite name in this way and receive correct name:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn 
suite_name = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${SUITE NAME}")   =>  Test Suite
```

BUT! When I try to use the same for approach with @{TEST TAGS}, I receive None:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn 
suite_name = BuiltIn().get_variable_value("@{TEST TAGS}")    =>  None
```

I think the problem is that I coded it wrong. Tell me how to write the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

the variable `@{TEST_TAGS}` is only available at a test level. This means you can't access it from suite level, like you try in your code snippet.

If you want all tags in a suite then you could try [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648826).

If you do want them at a test level you'll want to write a keyword in python for it like so:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn 
from robot.api.logger import console

def get_tags():
    console(BuiltIn().get_variable_value("@{TEST TAGS}"))
```

then in robot you can use:

```
dummy test case
    [Tags]    some tag     some other tag
    Get Tags
```

This will print `['some other tag', 'some tag']`

Comment: Yes, that's right! This is how I solved this problem yesterday, but I didn't have time to write an answer here. Really appreciate your answer and thank you for support! I'm sure it will be useful for someone.