# How to read force tag label using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

The application has two types of user with different access. I wrote two test suite for each user. If  user1 login then suite1 is executed and if user2 log in then suite2 executed. to achieve this I use 'Force Tag' concept.

I try to write python code which identifies the force tag of running suite and login with respective user. I also refer this "[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648826/how-to-print-available-tags-while-using-robot-framework ]" but not able to get the force tag label. anybody help me to get the label of force tag of suite.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can get the tag.
I am aware that you can pass the tag from python to Robot Framework, but not the opposite.
Like the command below that runs tests based on their tags:

```
pabot --processes 2 --randomize all --outputdir StagingReports -o StagingReports.xml -v ENV:qa  --exclude tag_eclude_exemple --include tag_include_exemple .\RootFolder
```

If this is not a good answer, please explain a bit more about your question.